# Does "more than 2" include 2?

Tags: numbers, comparative

In technical document in English, I read sentence of "more than 2". I usually just understand it as "two or more" since we generally translate it as similar sentence in Korean. (in Korean, there are separated single words for 'greater than or equal to' and 'greater than'.)

But in this case, I feel it means "greater than 2" because the technical context of the document need '> 2' not '>= 2'. So my question is, which is right understanding for "more than two". Is it "> 2" or ">= 2"? And more, if I need to write for ">= 2", which is clear way to write?

I think "two or more" is clear but is there any clear expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding

> **more than 2**

is > 2, meaning

> **greater than but not including 2**

your other phrase

> **two or more**

is very succinct and clear, you could also use

> **at least 2**

to mean "***>= 2***", it does not need to be entirely spelled out as

> **greater than or equal to 2**

Comment: **>=2** can also be written as "not less than two" or "at least two".

Comment: Yes, it can also be written that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are there any formal but shorter words for '>='?

Comment: Your example of "2 or more" is very succinct. You could also use "At least 2".